# Are there any negative consequences for taking the Memorex

Tags: stellaris

After excavating a dig site I found the Memorex, a device that erases memories and gives some nice stability and jobs output bonuses.

There is an option to not take the Memorex, are there any negative consequences when taking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of. I have chosen to take it and there weren't any negative consequences. It's still possible that there was a random chance in the background but I couldn't find any indication to support that.